# Running code from within custom timer job returns access denied

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to activate a site scoped feature from within a timer job and it returns access denied. How can I get enough permissions to perform this action?

Also I'm currently testing on a development machine where the timer service runs under my own admin account which is a sharepoint farm admin. However I still get an access denied error when running the timer job. It should have more than enough permissions to perform this action.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your timer job is running under the security context of a farm administrator, but the action you are trying to perform is a site-level action, not a farm level action. Try making your farm account a site collection administrator of the site your are working against, then execute the code.

Have you ever logged in to SharePoint as a farm or System account, and gotten access denied on the site? This is the issue you are facing.

Comment: Hi Derek, The site was created using the same account. It is listed as the site collection admin and I am able to logon to the site using the admin account. So I really can't see why I get an access denied.